# Наследование контрола в Silverlight

Tags: c#, наследование, silverlight, windows-phone-7, usercontrol

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

У меня есть `User Control`, с картинкой в бэкграунде. Описан таким образом:

```
       <Button some_parameters_here>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="wayToPicture.png" />
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Теперь, когда я меняю значение свойства `IsEnabled` кнопки, то бэкграунд исчезает при значении `false`, т.е. как будто сменилась видимость. Как можно сделать вместо этого смену цвета, как в обычном контроле? (т.е. при `IsEnabled = false`, картинка будет становиться черно-белой)

Я так понимаю, придется объявлять свой класс и наследовать его от контрола/кнопки (от чего именно?) и перегружать метод `IsEnabled`. В наследовании я,
 честно говоря, не силен, прошу помочь.

```
public class PaintedButton: Button // Control?
    {

  PaintedButton()
            :base()
        {
        }

   public override ???

     {
     }
   }
```

P.S. Так, я открыл для себя разницу между WPF и Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос пора закрывать, так что **решение**:

В app.xaml создаем свой стиль для кнопки, находим там VisualState = pressed и прописываем там свой вариант. В простейшем случае - тупо стираем все что там написано, тогда при нажатии не будет никакой реакции на это. (т.е. без веселого белого квадрата)

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
   ...
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
    <-- Если хотим что-то менять, то дальше пишем <StoryBoard> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Скрывается по тому, что у Вас тема `PresentationFramework.Aero` или др. не совсем стандартная. В случае с `Enable` кисть меняется и Ваша картинка пропадает. Можно сделать контент регулируемым, но я не советую. Предлагаю как вариант, очень простой, на мой взгляд, шаблон кнопки. Он переключает одно изображение на другое в зависимости от свойств. По аналогии можете научиться и др. вещам в `WPF`.

```
<Button IsEnabled="True">
     <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" /> - здесь ваш контент или текст
        <Button.Template>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
              <Grid>
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" x:Name="EnabledT"
                         Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/EnabledPic.jpg" />
                        <Image Stretch="Fill" x:Name="DisabledT" Visibility="Hidden"
                         Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/DisablePic.jpg" />
                        <ContentPresenter /> - Контент
              </Grid>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="EnabledT" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="DisabledT" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
             </Trigger>
             <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="EnabledT" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Setter TargetName="DisabledT" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
             </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     </ControlTemplate>
   </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Для WPF конечно работает. :) Sorry, ошибся с меткой. Плюс поставлю. Для Silverlight вероятно надо поколдовать над VisualStateManager.